# Find the Kth largest int in array

Tags: c++, algorithm, quickselect

I am trying to use quickselect in c++ to do this, but it keeps returning me the kth smallest element instead of the kth largest. Where is my logic wrong?

```
int partition(int* input, int p, int r)
{
    int pivot = input[r];

    while ( p < r )
    {
        while ( input[p] < pivot )
            p++;

        while ( input[r] > pivot )
            r--;

        if ( input[p] == input[r] )
            p++;
        else if ( p < r ) {
            int tmp = input[p];
            input[p] = input[r];
            input[r] = tmp;
        }
    }

    return r;
}

int quick_select(int* input, int p, int r, int k)
{
    if ( p == r ) return input[p];
    int j = partition(input, p, r);
    int length = j - p + 1;
    if ( length == k ) return input[j];
    else if ( k < length ) return quick_select(input, p, j - 1, k);
    else  return quick_select(input, j + 1, r, k - length);
}
```

What should I change to make this kth largest instead of kth smallest element?

Comment: It seems you partition your elements to be the small ones in the front and the big ones in the back. However, you select _k_ th element from the front rather than from the back. Either switch the directions around or select the _k_ th element from the back.

Comment: Note that in real code you normally want to use `std::nth_element` to do this instead of writing your own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the `<` and `>` in your code is reverse in `partition()` as @Dietmar Kühl mentioned,by change them,it works correctly.

besides,my suggestion is to use a normal `partition()` of quicksort as follow, for whose two index of which move in the same direction and one of them never surpasses another. It is not easy to make anyone confused.

```
int partition(int *input, int p, int r) {
    int pivot,i,j,tmp;
    pivot = input[r];
    i = p-1;
    for (j=p;j<=r-1;j++) {
        if (input[j]>= pivot) {
            i++;
        tmp = input[i];
        input[i] = input[j];
        input[j] = tmp;
        }
    }
    tmp = input[i+1];   
    input[i+1] = input[r];
    input[r] = tmp;
    return i+1;
}
```